# How can we validate response from api postman to real application ui in selenium python?

Tags: python, api, selenium, postman

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager import driver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def __init__(self):
   self.text1 = None
   self.name = None   
 
def test_get_response_from_application(self):
   driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael')
   self.name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[normalize-space()="Michael"]').text
   driver.close()
   return self.name 

def test_get_response_from_api(self):
   r = requests.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
   print(r.json())
   json_resp = r.json()
   self.text1 = json_resp['data'][0]['first_name']
   return self.text1

def validate_response(self):
   assert self.name == self.text1
   print('matched')
```

I am using this code to validate the data from api and application, but does not giving anything in output.  please help me with that. How to frame this code in functions, so that I can reuse it in framework?
Below code is working fine.

Comment: Hi. What error exactly are you facing?

Comment: It is giving nothing, passing the assertion statement, after putting wrong data as well.